# Does the usual interchange of derivative and limit theorem hold for the case of the frechet derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, reference-request

Consider a normed real vector space $V$, and $A$ a closed, bounded subset of $V$ with $f_n : A \subset V \rightarrow V$ a sequence of functions such that the sequence $D(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $g : A \subseteq V \rightarrow V$ on $A$, where D is the frechet derivative, and $\exists x \in A$ such that $\lim f_n(x)$ converges. Does $g = D(f)$?

I would hope that the usual proof carries over from the case of the usual derivative in $\mathbb{R}$, but I can't find any references on this.

Comment: If you consider $D$ to be a map: $\mathcal C _{\infty}\to \mathscr L(V,V)$ then you can look at $\Vert D(f)-D(f_n)\Vert= \Vert D((f-f_n)\Vert\leq \Vert D\Vert \cdot \Vert f-f_n\Vert$. So the issue is whether $D$ is bounded.

Comment: This isn't true even in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo You're right. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The analogous theorem does hold if $A$ is a connected subset of a Banach space. The following is the statement of result $(8.6.3)$ in my edition of Dieudonné's "Foundations of Modern Analysis":

> Let $A$ be an open connected subset in a Banach space $E$, $(f_n)$ a sequence of differentiable mappings of $A$ into a Banach space $F$. Suppose that: (1) there exists one point $x_0 \in A$ such that the sequence $(f_n(x_0))$ converges in $F$; (2) for every point $a \in A,$ there is a ball $B(a)$ of center $a$ contained in $A$ and such that in $B(a)$ the sequence $(f_n^\prime)$ converges uniformly. Then for each $a \in A,$ the sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly in $B(a)$; moreover, if, for each $x \in A,$ $f(x)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)$ and $g(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n^\prime(x),$ then $g(x)=f^\prime(x),$ for each $x \in A.$

You can also find this in H. Cartan's "Calcul Différentiel".